# Variances add, and therefore subtract?

Tags: variance, signal-processing

Variances add, so va + vb = vc. If I know what va and vc are, can I estimate vb by vb = vc - va ?

More specifically, I have a noisy statistical time series which consists of the pure signal plus noise. If I know the variance for the whole noisy signal, and for the pure signal, can I subtract to obtain the variance for the noise?

Edit: I ask because textbooks say that the variance of difference between two variables is also their sum, ie vb = vc + va. This is incompatible with va + vb = vc. They cannot both be right. What is the solution to this paradox, assuming that they are independent?

Comment: *Assuming that they are independent*.

Comment: There is no paradox and no incompatibility unless you are hoping, *contra* all evidence and mathematical definitions to the contrary, that variance is a linear function. The mistake lies in the limitations of your notation. Following convention, let $A$ and $B$ be independent random variables with $C=A+B$ so that $$\operatorname{Var}C=\operatorname{Var}(A)+\operatorname{Var}(B).$$ From this it follows that $$\operatorname{Var}(B)=\operatorname{Var}(C-A)=\operatorname{Var}(C)+\operatorname{Var}(A)-2\operatorname{Cov}(C,A)$$ and you can easily work out the rest.